# What values can an OpenGL shader access that are set before rendering?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

If I have a simple OpenGL shader that is applied to many cubes at once, then uniform values get slow. I have noticed that things like glColor3f don't slow it down as much (at least from what I have tried) but am currently using glColor3f as a sort of hack so that the shader can read gl_Color and I can use it similarly to a uniform for determing which side of the cube is being rendered for face-indepent flat lighting.

I am using displaylists so I used glColor3f because it baked into the list, and simply did a different color before every face while creating the list. Now, I want to set more values (not in the displaylist this time) before rendering.

What calls from OpenGL can I do that can be read in the shader? I am needing to send 6 ints from 0-8 into the shader before rendering, but I could probably manage to shrink that later on.

Comment: This kind of thing is a lot easier if you use modern OpenGL, instead of trying to mix and match the fixed-function pipeline (`glColor3f`) and obsolete APIs (display lists) with newer features (shaders).  Typically, you would define a combination of attributes, uniforms, uniform buffers, textures, shader storage buffers, et cetera, and the shader can read all of those.  It sounds like you want attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use uniform blocks or uniforms with datatype `ivec2`, `ivec3` or `ivec4`, with them you can write 2, 3, or 4 `int` at once.

Aapart from this there are some built-in uniforms. Apart from the matrices, these are `gl_DepthRange`, `gl_Fog`, `gl_LightSource[gl_MaxLights]`, `gl_LightModel`, `gl_FrontLightModelProduct`, `gl_BackLightModelProduct`, `gl_FrontLightProduct[gl_MaxLights]`, `gl_BackLightProduct[gl_MaxLights]`, `gl_FrontMaterial`, `gl_BackMaterial`, `gl_Point`, `gl_TextureEnvColor[gl_MaxTextureUnits]`, `gl_ClipPlane[gl_MaxClipPlanes]`, `gl_EyePlaneS[gl_MaxTextureCoords]`, `gl_EyePlaneT[gl_MaxTextureCoords]`, `gl_EyePlaneR[gl_MaxTextureCoords]`, `gl_EyePlaneQ[gl_MaxTextureCoords]`, `gl_ObjectPlaneS[gl_MaxTextureCoords]`, `gl_ObjectPlaneT[gl_MaxTextureCoords]`, `gl_ObjectPlaneR[gl_MaxTextureCoords]` and `gl_ObjectPlaneQ[gl_MaxTextureCoords]`.

But the intended manner to read global data from shaders are uniform variables. Another way would be to encode information in textures.

Comment: Would using VBO's and other newer rendering methods help speed it up? I am making something similar to Minecraft for fun and learning. I have Frustum Culling and it doesn't render blocks completely surrounded, so without passing uniforms I can get a pretty good framerate. Now that I want to implement flat lighting for individual faces, I did the stuff I said to control a face's lighting. It works, but if I have enough blocks then it lags way more than I would like. If I set a close render distance the system does work, though.

Comment: @Cello Code I have less experience with VBO's. I recomend to read answer of this question [Does interleaving in VBOs speed up performance when using VAOs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853713/does-interleaving-in-vbos-speed-up-performance-when-using-vaos?rq=1)